# How to translate proper name that contain one diacritical mark?

Tags: translation, proper-nouns, diacritical-marks

I'm currently writing an English report, and I have to include a street name in it. Unfortunately, this name includes a character that is not present in the English alphabet: an `è`. Every other letter is writable in English.

How should I translate this name? I know usually proper names don't have to change when translated from a language to another, but what about this special character? I wonder about it because someone who never learned French wouldn't know how to pronounce it. But if I replace it with an `e`, it won't sound the same.

For precision, people who will correct my work do speak French, so would be able to read it. But I ask for a potential future case of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not in the dictionary (café is now just cafe in English, for example), leave in the diacritic. Non-French speakers are not going to know how to pronounce it anyway, and if a French speaker is reading it, you'll have spelled it correctly for them.

Comment: "café" is now "cafe"? I wouldn't think it at all odd seeing "café" myself, but maybe I'm in the minority nowadays. (: (Native American English speaker.)

Answer (score 3):

For a proper noun, one would still use the diacritical mark. However, if it is not for a proper name, and there is an Anglicized equivalent, I would use the equivalent.

The "MLA Sister Site" contains a [guide for inserting diacritical marks](http://mla-format.com/blog/2013/02/18/how-to-create-accent-marks-in-non-english-words/) using an English keyboard, specifically, it states the purpose of the list is to type non-English names.

Comment: Additionally, this question is similar to http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/823/should-i-use-diacritical-marks

Answer (score 0):

Why not write it in the French way? You find a lot of words of French, Italian or German in English books.